# Typings for a List.flat method?

Tags: typescript, types

I want to make my own implementation of a list in Typescript. I have reasons for this, there are a few Array methods I want to have and the nicest way I can think to accomplish this is by creating my own in-house List class.

Two of the methods I want right now are flat and flatMap, doing the same thing as Array.flat and Array.flatMap.

This is basically what I have right now.

```
class List<T> { //T can be anything, numbers, list of numbers
    items: T[];
    constructor(items: T[]) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    flat<U>(): List<U> {
        //My method here.
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is I want U to drop one layer of List.

If T is of type `List<number | List<number | List<number>>>`

I want U to be of type `List<number | List<number>>`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I assume `flatMap()` isn't the main point of the question, so I'm focusing on `flat()` in my answer.  If you need `flatMap()` addressed also, you might want to edit the question to indicate that you need both of these, both in the title and in the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a hint from [the TypeScript standard library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/38da7c600c83e7b31193a62495239a0fe478cb67/lib/lib.es2019.array.d.ts#L21-L26) for the output of `Array<T>.prototype.flat()`.  The actual typing is complicated because it can accept a depth of greater than `1`.  So instead of reading the library directly, let's just see what comes out when we call `flat()` on a generic array in some test code:

```
function f<T>(arr: Array<T>) {
  const flattened = arr.flat();
  // const flattened = (T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? InnerArr : T)[]
}
```

So, `arr` is `T[]`, and `flattened` is `(T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? InnerArr  : T)[]`.  That's a new array type whose element is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  This type inspects `T` and checks whether it is an array or not.  If it is, it gets the element type of that array `InnerArr`; if it is not, it keeps `T`.  So if `T` is `number`, then the output element type is `number`.  But if `T` is `number[]`, the output element type is `number`.  The conditional type is [distributive over unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), so if `T` is `number | number[]`, then the output element type is `number | number`, which is just `number`.

---

Now that we've seen that, let's write something similar in `List`:

```
class List<T> {

  items: T[];
  constructor(items: T[]) {
    this.items = items;
  }

  flat(): List<T extends List<infer U> ? U : T> {
    return new List(this.items.reduce((a, i) =>
      [...a, ...i instanceof List ? i.items : [i]], [] as any[]));
  }

  toString() {
    return "List(" + this.items.join(",") + ")";
  }

}
```

The output of `flat()` is `List<T extends List<infer U> ? U : T>`... that is, if `T` is itself a `List`, then we pull out the element type and use that; otherwise we just use `T`.  The same distributive stuff happens here too, so hopefully `List<number | List<number | List<number>>>` will turn into `List<number | List<number>>`.
Just for fun I implemented `flat()`: note that any implementation of `flat()` will probably need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like (in my case, I'm using `as any[]`), since the compiler cannot easily verify assignability to a conditional type that depends on an unresolved type parameter like `T`.  I also added a `toString()` so that we can see a compact representation in the tests below:

---

Let's test it out:

```
const foo = new List([1, new List([new List([2, 3]), 4, new List([5, 6]), 7, 8]), 9]);
// const foo: List<number | List<number | List<number>>>
console.log(foo.toString()); // List(1,List(List(2,3),4,List(5,6),7,8),9)

const bar = foo.flat();
// const bar: List<number | List<number>>
console.log(bar.toString()); // List(1,List(2,3),4,List(5,6),7,8,9)"

const baz = bar.flat();
// const baz: List<number>
console.log(baz.toString()); // List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

const qux = baz.flat();
// const qux: List<number>
console.log(qux.toString());  // List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Looks good!  Each invocation of `flat()` removes up to one nested layer of `List` from the output type.  And the output values conform to that.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.2.3#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-iOAGMUxFZYPabEcVBXE8ZuQA)

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much. Im goona play around with it and see if I can get rid of the assertion to any[] but even if I cant figure that out this is great!